# Object is possibly 'undefined' Typescript in find function method

Tags: javascript, typescript

I really don't know how I can capture the error. Could someone help me on this?

If you have better solution (If anything looks better, it's also great)

```
interface Props {
    prevCases: Array<Case>
}

export function MyFunction(props) {
  const { prevCases } = this.props;
  const myType = prevCases               << Object is possibly 'undefined'.
    .find((case: Case) => case?.id === myId).resultItems
    ?.find((item: Item) => item.name === myPath)
    ?.type;
  console.log(ArrayA[myType]);    << Type 'undefined' cannot be used as an index type.
...
```

Comment: If one of the `find`'s produce nothing, it will return undefined, meaning your code is stuck with an undefined value you're now trying to pass off as an index to an array

Comment: Side note, this is not easily read. I would refactor to make it easier on the eyes. Compilers do the hard work to make it easier on the wire, but you read code more than write it.

Comment: yeah,, something got added to `?` and it's difficult to read

Comment: I added more lines . Does that help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use simplified/readable code, so readers could understand.
1 issue is you cannot write this.prop this looks for global variable, replace that by just prop.
Debug further issue by using try catch block

```
interface Props {
    prevCases: any[]
}
let myId = 1;
let myPath = 'abc';
function MyFunction(props : any[]) {
    try {
        const myType = props.filter(prop => prop ? prop['id'] === myId : false)
                            .filter(prop => prop ? prop['name'] === myPath : false); 

        myType.forEach(item => console.log(item['value']));
    }
    catch(Error){
        console.log(Error.message);
    }
}
MyFunction([null,{'id':2,'name':'abc','value':'b'},{'id':1,'name':'abc','value':'c'}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

When using object destructuring, the property value can potentially be `undefined`:

```js
const { prevCases } = this.props;
```

is the same as:

```js
const prevCases = this.props.prevCases;
```

and Typescript doesn't know the type of `props`, so it doesn't know that the property `prevCases` exist, you need to explicitely tell Typescript that the `props` argument is of type `Props`. To do that, you need to declare the type in the function declaration as such:

```js
export function MyFunction(props: Props) {
 // Your function body
}
```

and that way, Typescript will be use that no matter what happens, the `props` parameter will always be of type `Props`

Comment: Also those `?.` operators can return `undefined`.

Comment: Also, using the `.find()` method will either return a value or `undefined` (as explained [there](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find#Return_value)), so in your case Typescript will assume that the `.find()` method might returns an `undefined`.

And because you use the `?.` syntax to chain properties, it will propagate the `undefined` property. That's why the `mType` variable can't be used as an index: because it is potentially `undefined`. If you're sure that it will always be defined,you can use the `!!.` syntax to access properties.